# Opening a terminal window from Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, terminal, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, anaconda3

I have a Jupyter Notebook that prepares certain files. Then, I open a `zsh` terminal window and run a Python file (`computations.py`), which requires the files prepared. I run this computation outside of Jupyter because it takes a long time, uses considerable resources, and prints a very long output in the terminal, which could cause problems if run directly in the notebook.

Is there a way to open an independent window of the `zsh` terminal by executing a cell in Jupyter Notebook and run some prespecified commands in said terminal? Specifically, I would like to run `conda activate my_env; time python computations.py`).

Please note that I do not want to run the code `computations.py` in Jupyter itself (e.g. using `%%bash` or `!python computations.py`).

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: You tagged your question JupyterLab. JupyterLab does provide an ability to [open terminals](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/terminal.html). Is your question about how to switch it to use zsh instead of bash?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The question is how to trigger the execution of specific code in a new terminal window by running a code cell in a Jupyter notebook. If possible, I would like the zsh terminal to pop up as a separate window and execute the desired code.

Comment: Sounds like a task for https://github.com/jtpio/ipylab